# Getting exception in android 6.0 when i use com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider

Tags: android

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider from ProcessRecord{8beeb65 18868:com.rehq.app/u0a175} (pid=18868, uid=10175) requires com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ or com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE
```

Anyone have any idea to resolve this exception?

This exception generated in android 6.0.

I don't know how to give com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ or com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE permission on android 6.0

Comment: was your problem solved?

Comment: till not, but i will try after some time. i hope your answer help me.

Comment: public class BaseApplication extends Application {  

I am extends Application not ActivityCompat.

Comment: What is this?? can you explain

Comment: Actually, i need request permission in Application not ActivityCompat.
It give me exception like requestionpermission() in activitycompat cannot be applied to.

Comment: Why would you do that??

Comment: Becuase this is my base class in my application,

public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    public ConnectionService mService;
    public static ConnectionService.ServiceCallbacks serviceCallbacks = null;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static BaseApplication appControllerContext;//SUSHIL
    private FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
    .....

Comment: You should ask permissions in SplashScreen activity of your application.

Comment: Do you have any constructor in this base class??

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Let me try.

Thanks...

Comment: Welcome, if my answer helped you dont forget to accept it and vote up the answer so it may help others in future

Comment: Done, so solution worked or not?

Comment: Just run application i will tell you in some time.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider from ProcessRecord{ab1124 10588:com.rehq.app/u0a175} (pid=10588, uid=10175) requires com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ or com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144923/discussion-between-avi-and-abdul-kawee).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you are not allowing permission, as starting android 6.0 you have to explicitly ask for permissions

First declare permission in manifest as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

And then in your activity ask permission as follows

```
boolean permission;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        permission = Settings.System.canWrite(context);
    } else {
        permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
    if (permission) {
        //do your code
    }  else {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
            context.startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS}, MainActivity.CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps